# Spring security check is header present with some fixed value

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Let's say I have spring boot rest service which I would like to secure with this simple logic, 
if there is header "token" with a value "123456" then request is fine, and I should process it,
if not then I should sent back unauthorized 401 http error.

How I can implement this logic in spring boot 1.5.

Comment: Did you make attempt to implement this? if not, please do it and post your work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By implementing a `GenericFilterBean`.

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // get header and validate from request object
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

And hooking the filter into your security configuration.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.authorizeRequests()
            // other security config
            .addFilterBefore(new CustomAuthenticationFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}
```

Comment: Thannks, could you please say what should I do in filter when header value is wrong, ? Should I write directly to response object and return from function without calling filterChain.dofilter?

Comment: Yes, if your requirements are not satisfied do not proceed with the request filter.